# Strikethrough and Roman numeral analysis in Schoenberg

Tags: theory, notation, chord-theory, analysis, roman-numerals

I've bumped into this very brief analysis in *Structural Function of Harmony* by Schoenberg and I've found that strikethrough **V**. Now, the chord is an D diminished seventh chord, leading to the dominant and the symbol seems the one used for secondary dominants, despite the (fallible) fact that I know one usually would write II instead of V, since we are in C major.

Where am I wrong? Is there a kind of Schoenberg's notation I'm missing? I searched through glossaries but I found nothing.

[image: Roman numeral analysis in Schoenberg]

Comment: A secondary dominant, as in D7 leading to G in key C, is more often named V/V. I like II, but it's not usual.

Comment: The diminished chord is a B diminished, rather than D. It's the vii chord of C, not a predominant of G. A D diminished chord would be spelled D-F-Ab-Cb.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<s>V</s> means altered V: Schoenberg is analysing this functionally, and there is no real change of function here. The diminished seventh here is acting both as an appoggiatura to V (A♭ to G, F to G in the bass), and as a form of V itself (dominant minor ninth with the root truncated).

Edit: He's also signalling that we're in C *minor* - that's what the lower case **c** means.

Comment: I'm no expert on the notation, but it strikes me (no pun intended!) that the first chord is *functionally* some sort of dominant chord, but it doesn't actually *contain* the dominant (i.e. the note G). Whatever it *looks* like, to me it doesn't *sound* like a supertonic chord or a "dominant of the dominant" - it's a dominant chord with some appoggiaturas, which by happenstance doesn't contain its root..

Comment: @alephzero, that's more or less what I said, no? :D More seriously, vii°7, when used normally, almost always acts like V♭9.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, it's like calling the typical IV-Ic-V-I cadence just IV-V(crossed)-V-I, to signify that the function is still that of a V chord, with little difference, am I right? 
Regarding that "c", I thought it is standing for a minor key, too, but then GMaj suggested me it was CMaj, but I think it's not so easy.

Comment: I'm inclined to say not really. Generally Ic only shares the bass with V - you can consider it a double appoggiatura of sorts (which is maybe the best way of looking at it) or a kind of predominant, but Ic doesn't generally *act* like a dominant in its own right, so it is hard to call it altered V. In the Götterdämmerung example, the voice leading of vii°7 is set up as an appoggiatura (or accented auxiliary in the second instance, I suppose), but the notes are all part of a dominant ninth anyway - the only thing missing is the root. <*more*>

Comment: As for the key, I'd have to check the context to be 100% sure (although I think we can trust Schoenberg to get it essentially right), but the A♭ strongly suggests a move into the minor. Using the scale degree ♭6 in a dominant-style chord doesn't absolutely guarantee being in the minor mode, but I think we can trust that AS took the context into account. In minor mode cadences in classical music, V (rather than v) is the norm - it provides the leading tone (B♮ in this case) needed for a strong cadence to the tonic.

Comment: Oh, those are really good points! So Ic is just an appoggiatura and has no dominant role itself while the vii°7 chord has dominant role, since its leading tones tend to move towards the I chord (and in fact is part of a dominant ninth). Moreover, sure, making the Bb a B♮ is typical, and so having V, which is stronger than v. Finally, I was not doubting AS =D I only thought he could have used a different notation, which could still be possible, but, as you say, we would need the context.

Answer (score -1):

Look up Walter Piston's *Harmony* textbook; this is a "Rootless" Flat-Nine Chord, built upon a second inversion dominant.

Comment: I changed the end to "second inversion dominant"; feel free to roll it back if this is not what you meant.